# Build rights to user on Jenkins Jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I need to provide build rights to a user on lots of jenkins jobs and currently I have to provide by opening say 50 jobs and provide the result via UI as per below:

[image]

Please suggest some automated way so that I can provide the rights via command or groovy code. I just provide the name of the jobs in a text file and it reads from the file and provide the build rights to the particular user as I keep on getting such request time to time and I have to open(sometime) 100 jobs at a time.

Comment: What [authorization strategy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Securing+Jenkins) are you using? We use [Role-Based strategy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Role+Strategy+Plugin). No unauthenticated access, regex based project roles, leveraging AD security groups for memberships. You can reverse [export-role-strategy-permissions-to-csv.groovy](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/export-role-strategy-permissions-to-csv.groovy) to add them.

Comment: We use project based strategy, moreover there is no AD yet. But we need to give permission to bulk jobs so was finding the way instead of manual effort.

Comment: I suppose it's not much more complicated to manage as individuals than groups, just makes for more entities. You can still leverage the export script, just look in javadoc for the project -based classes. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535114/jenkins-groovy-remove-user-access-from-project-matrix-authorization-strategy) seems to do the reverse (remove) on a project strategy

Comment: Can we have the script to grant build right to a particular job?

Comment: You can, but do you want to? You'd have to set up an explicit rule for every job! Have you considered using folders and a naming convention? That way you grant people a role based on a set of jobs; lots less grief.